# Sed not finding/ replacing all characters in a directory

Tags: sed

I am trying to find and replace single characters in a number of text files in a directory. Apologies for the possible duplication but I have not been able to find an answer in other sed threads.

I used Homebrew to install gnu-sed, and I'm using the command:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec gsed -i -e 's/ñ/–/g' '{}' \;
```

I have a 'test' file containing the characters I need replacing in the directory, and these are all found and replaced correctly. But other characters in other text files are not. e.g. 'Weíre to Denmark ñ all' (ñ also isn't found/ replaced).

Why might this be? How can I fix it? Thank you!

Edit - Output of

```
$ od -c filethatworks.txt | head -2
0000000    –  **  **  \n   –  **  **  \n   “  **  **  \n   “  **  **  \n
0000020    —  **  **  \n   —  **  **  \n   -  \n   “  **  **  \n   “  **
$ od -c filethatdoesnot.txt | head -2
0000000    T   h   o   s   e       b   l   e   s   s   e   d       d   a
0000020    y   s       o   f       s   u   m   m   e   r       a   r   e
```

For a file that works, the file command returns

```
test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

and for one that does not:

```
ca001_mci_17071971.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRL
F line terminators
```

Comment: Things always get confusing when unicode is involved. :) Can you please include in your question the output of `od -c filethatworks.txt | head -2` and `od -c filethatdoesnot.txt | head -2`, as well as perhaps what the `file` command returns when pointed at each of these files? I suspect that the problem you're experiencing has more to do with [how your text files are encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) rather than your usage of `gsed`. The `ñ` in your command line translates to a series of bytes that may not be the same series within your file, depending on encoding.

Comment: I was afraid it was a unicode problem...have edited to include those, sorry I am new to using the command line etc.

Comment: Check out AlexP's answer. `iconv` is what I was going to suggest as well. You may need to do a little experimentation or further research to determine what input encoding works with your file that doesn't work. And building on what AlexP suggested, you may not be able to trust `sed` to handle special characters that are outside `US-ASCII`. Check your results carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Characters* are human concepts. When characters are to be represented in computer files, they need to be *encoded*. Encoding associates each character with an integer called a *code point*.

For example, take the character "**ă**" (that's lower case "a" with a breve on top, used in Romanian spelling for the vowel `/ə/`); in the old days of MS-DOS, we quite often used an encoding called "[code page 852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852)", where "**ă**" has the code point 199. Then Windows came, and on Windows we often used an encoding called "[code page 1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)", where "**ă**" has the code point 227. Then came Unicode, and in Unicode "**ă**" has the code point 259.

Since Unicode code points can have values larger than 255, there must be a way to represent them using bytes with values between 0 and 255. Those methods are called "Unicode Transformation Formats" (UTF), of which the most widely used are [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (very popular in Linux) and [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (of two kinds, little and big endian, and very popular on Windows). In UTF-8, "**ă**" is represented as two bytes, with the values 196 and 131 (by the rules of UTF-8, those two bytes together represent code point 259); in little endian UTF-16, "**ă**" is represented by two bytes, with the values 3 and 1 (by the rules of little endian UTF-16, those two bytes together represent code point 259).

The point is that in order to make sense of a text file you need to know (1) what encoding is used, and (2) in the case of Unicode, what transformation format is used. Now, on Linux and on the Web we are very close to a consensus that all text is represented in UTF-8; nevertheless, old files still exist, and occasionally new files come from Windows, so there is a very nice program called [`iconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/iconv.1posix.html) (available both on Linux and [on Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)) which is used to translate text files from one encoding into another.

For example, assuming that your problematic file is encoded in Windows-1252 (also called ANSI by the Windows documentation, although the American National Standards Institute had nothing to do with it), you could say

```
iconv -f windows-1250 -t utf-8 ca001_mci_17071971.txt | gsed -e 's/ñ/–/g' '{}'
```

Sadly, there is no way to use `sed -i`; you must write a temporary output file, then rename the temporary output file on top of the source file, of course after checking that everything went well.

Comment: Great answer. Much better than the one I was still trying to grow in my head. +1. :)  I'll point out that the OP's mention of "Homebrew" probably indicates that use of macOS, which generally uses BSD variants of tools .. unless GNU versions are manually installed with something like Homebrew or Macports. The `iconv` binary is installed with the command `brew install libiconv` or `port install libiconv` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth answer! That's great. @ghoti yes macOS, thanks :) Having played around with iconv I wonder if it's better for me to convert the whole file to utf-8, using {iconv -f windows-1250 -t UTF-8 ca001_mci_17071971.txt > outputfile.txt} ? This seems to work but might I run in to issues later...

Comment: @ConfusedfromWandsworth: I would suggest that you maintain all text files encoded in UTF-8; if the original file has a different encoding I would make an UTF-8 encoded copy, named by adding `.UTF-8` between the name and the suffix, for example, `ca001_mci_17071971.UTF-8.txt`, so that you know from where it came.